# What's happening if one of concurent lock on a table rename the locked table?

Tags: postgresql

I've hundred of insert as following each minutes:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

  INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (...);

COMMIT;
```

And I've the following transaction which will occured once:

```
BEGIN ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

  LOCK TABLE table1 IN ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;

  /* Rename the locked table */
  ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table1_renamed;

  /* And I recreate the table */
  CREATE TABLE table1 (
    ...
  );

COMMIT;
```

The second transaction will blocked all INSERTs until it commits.

When it commits, will inserts be proceed on the new `table1` or on the renamed one?

In other world are locks acquired on object's name (so it's resilient on rename operation) or on object's reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects id (`oid`) at the time the statement is prepared and executed. Pg_locks doesn't even store the relations name.

```
        View "pg_catalog.pg_locks"
       Column       |   Type   | Modifiers 
--------------------+----------+-----------
 locktype           | text     | 
 database           | oid      | 
 relation           | oid      | 
 page               | integer  | 
 tuple              | smallint | 
 virtualxid         | text     | 
 transactionid      | xid      | 
 classid            | oid      | 
 objid              | oid      | 
 objsubid           | smallint | 
 virtualtransaction | text     | 
 pid                | integer  | 
 mode               | text     | 
 granted            | boolean  | 
 fastpath           | boolean  |
```